# Parent div does not grow to fit content

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs that are inside a parent div, but the parent div "main" won't adjust the height to fit all the contents of div inside.

```html
<div id="main" style="width: 1000px; height: 100% overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="menu" style="width:250px; float: left;">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu items</li>
      <li>Menu items</li>
      <li>Menu items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="width:500px; height: 1000px float: left;">
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu" style="width:250px; float: left;">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu items</li>
      <li>Menu items</li>
      <li>Menu items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above the height of "content" is 1000px but the parent "main" won't adjust to be 1000px, it just stops displaying the content of "content" since "main" runs out of height.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you have to clear thefloats and height:100% may be a problem depending on what the parent of main is. Clearing the float should solve the problem

Comment: typo issue: missing `;` after height:100%

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent div  grow to fit content, you could use `height:max-content`,

Also, you miss the `;` for height which makes `height:1000px`  and `height:100%` for `content` not working

```css
#main{
 height:max-content;
 border:2px solid black;

}
#content{
 width:500px;
 height: 1000px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="width: 1000px; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="menu" style="width:250px; float: left;">
<ul>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content" >
<p>CONTENT</p>
</div>

<div id="menu" >
<ul>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
<li>Menu items</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have left a bunch of semicolons out of your css, by the way.
You are specifically declaring the height of your container div to be 100% (that's 100% of the view/window), and setting it's overflow to 'hidden.' So the behaviour you describe is to be expected.
Try removing the `overflow` and `height` properties to see what happens.

Comment: `height: 100%` does not apply 100% height of the view/window. That would be `100vh`. `height: 100%` means 100% of the parents height. However this requires the parent to have a defined height instead of a calculated height to fit content.

Comment: touché, but I was assuming that the parent of the container was `<body>`.